# Facebook pixel helper with function(e)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, facebook

I need some help. I'm using opencart 1.5.6 and on category page I have this code:

```
<a data-price='<?php echo $price; ?>' data-id='<?php echo $product_id; ?>' id="wish_list_pixel" title="<?php echo $this->language->get('button_wishlist'); ?>" onclick="addToWishList('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');">
```

and on same page I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( '#wish_list_pixel' ).on('click', function(e) {
        fbq('track', 'AddToWishlist', {
            content_ids: [$(e.target).data('id')],
            content_type: 'product',
            value: $(e.target).data('price'),
            currency: 'RON'
        });
    });
</script>
```

On Facebook pixel helper it sees only this:

```
Pixel Code:
fbq('track', 'AddToWishlist', {
content_ids: [$(e.target)
```

And don't send any info to Facebook.